# Проблема с Rspec с выведением данных через puts

Tags: ruby, тестирование, rspec

Не судите строго мой код, что в коде надо поменять, чтоб мой тест на Rspec правильно работал.

```
require "rspec"
 class A
 attr_accessor :name
  def name1
  puts "Hello #{@name}"
 end
end

describe "Hello" do
 it "Hello Mari" do
 name3=A.new
 name3.name="Mari"
 expect(name3.name1).to output("Hello Mari") 
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте `rspec` тесты командой, что не удивительно, `rspec path/to/file_spec.rb`.

Если же вы хотите запускать тест командой `ruby some_spec.rb` - подключайте авторан: `require 'rspec/autorun'`.

Чтобы проверить вывод в поток примеру надо передать блок и указать "матчеру" `output`, что вы ожидаете вывод в стандартный поток вывода:

```
expect { obj.foo }.to output('expected string').to_stdout
```

Учитывайте, что метод `puts` добавит перенос строки. Итого ваш тест будет выглядеть так:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

class A
  attr_accessor :name

  def name1
    puts "Hello #{@name}"
  end
end

describe "Hello" do
  it "Hello Mari" do
    name3 = A.new
    name3.name = "Mari"

    expect { name3.name1 }.to output("Hello Mari\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

Для таких простых тестов для чистоты можно воспользоваться [неявным объявлением объекта тестирования](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject):

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

class A
  attr_accessor :name

  def name1
    puts "Hello #{@name}"
  end
end

RSpec.describe A do
  it "should say hello with name to stdout" do
    subject.name = "Mari"

    expect { subject.name1 }.to output("Hello Mari\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

Comment: спасибо вам я вас упомяну в своем ютуб канале ) вы очень хорошо и доходчиво объяснили я очень рад вам за помощь)